# Docker containers have lost with no reason

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-container

I have been using 3-4 Docker containers for 1-2 months. However, I hibernate my PC instead of shutdown and before hibernate I stop Docker engine everyday for the last weeks. However, today I cannot see my containers and there is only "No containers running" message on Docker dashboard. I restarted many times and finally update to latest version and restarted PC, but still no containers. I also tried Docker factory reset, but nothing is changed. SO, how can I access my containers?

I tried to list containers via: `docker container ls`, but there is no container listed. So, have my containers has gone even with no reason?

Comment: A similar (catastrofic) issue happened to me too some time ago. Do you have the images yet? `docker image ls --all'.

Comment: Do you use docker compose or how did you initially start the container? Maybe they are just in a stopped state. What does `docker container ls -a` gives you?

Comment: @AntonioPetricca I run `docker image ls --all`, but there seems to be no image :(

Comment: @agentsmith `docker container ls -a` or  `docker container ls --a` gives error indicating there is an error with the usage of that command. I also tried with `all` instead of `a`, but still the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: I also think that there is a problem related to mounting containers or volumes. but how can I reach or re-mount?

Comment: Sorry.. overread Antonios's comment. It's the same command. Can you you add the error of `-a` to  your question?

Comment: The error may not be useful, because it is related to the usage of the command. It is "_unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a. See 'docker --help'. Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND. A self-sufficient runtime for containers_".

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can list stopped containers with

```
docker container ls -a
```

Then check the logs on those containers of they will not start. However...

> I also tried Docker factory reset

At this point those containers, images, and volumes are most likely gone. I don't believe there's a recovery after that step.

Comment: Thank you very much. Fortunately, there is not important data and I backed up the important database before. At this stage, I need to reinstall it properly. So, could you have at **[Should I install Docker on WSL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67721019/should-i-install-docker-on-wsl-on-windows)**?